# Angular2, unsubsribe from event in ngOnDestroy

Tags: angular, eventemitter

In my application I have some components that communicate by means of  `EventService`.

```ts
@Injectable()
export class EventService {
  public myEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() {}
}
```

This service is injected in a `EmitterComponent` that emits the event when a button is clicked

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'emitter',
  template: `<button (click)="onClick()">Click me</button>`,
})
export class EmitterComponent {
  constructor(private eventService:EventService) {}
  onClick() {
    this.eventService.myEvent.emit();
  }
}
```

and in a `ReceiverComponent` that subscribes to the event and for each event received increments a counter

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'receiver',
  template: `Count: {{count}}`,
})
export class ReceiverComponent {
  public count = 0;
  constructor(private eventService:EventService) {
    this.eventService.myEvent.subscribe(() => this.count++;);
  }
}
```

The application has multiple views (in this example just two): `PageA` and `PageB`. `EmitterComponent` and `ReceiverComponent` are in `PageA`. Every time I go to `PageB` and come back to `PageA`, a new `ReceiverComponent` is created and when I click the button in `EmitterComponent`, the event callback function of `ReceiverComponent` is executed several times.

To avoid this I unsubscribe `ReceiverComponent` from `myEvent` in `ngOnDestroy`

```ts
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.eventService.myEvent.unsubscribe();
}
```

but this causes the following Exception

```ts
EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of ReceiverComponent!.
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Error: Cannot subscribe to a disposed Subject
```

How can I avoid that? How to unsubscribe correctly?

For a better understanding I've created this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/GRpKK8aWTOvgyI4MxS0i?p=preview) where you can see the error and some comments in the console.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You get a subscription from `.subscribe()`. Use its `unsubscribe()` method to cancel the subscription.

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'receiver',
  template: `Count: {{count}}`,
})
export class ReceiverComponent {
  public count = 0;
  private subscription;
  constructor(private eventService:EventService) {
    this.subscription = this.eventService.myEvent.subscribe(() => this.count++;);
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

See also

- [how to unsubscribe several subscriber in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37695553/how-to-unsubscribe-several-subscriber-in-angular-2/37697421#37697421)
- [timer.unsubscribe is not a function Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181169/timer-unsubscribe-is-not-a-function-angular2/40181223#40181223)

Comment: That's exactly what I did, but this causes "Error: Cannot subscribe to a disposed Subject" when I change view to pageB and go back to pageA

Comment: Doesn't look the same to me. Am I missing something? In your question you use `this.eventService.myEvent.unsubscribe();` vs `subscription.unsubscribe();`.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, my bad, I didn't noticed the difference. Now it works, thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you need this? this.subscription is a class variable and should be automatically destroyed with the rest of the class?

Comment: @TGH good question. I don't know if `ReceiverComponent` can be GCed when `eventService.myEvent` still references a closure that references `ReceiverComponent.count`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer The OP's question that you answer here was posted almost a month after my question that you marked as a dupe of this one was.  You have this backwards....

Comment: You are right, somehow looked at a wrong date.

Answer (score 2):

I think your should cancel the subscription, as described below:

```
export class ReceiverComponent {
  public count = 0;
  private id;

  constructor(private eventService:EventService) {
    this.id = Date.now();
    console.log("ReceiverComponent constructor " + this.id);
    this.subscription = this.eventService.myEvent.subscribe(() => {
      console.log("count " + this.count + " (id ReceiverComponent instance: " + this.id + ")");
      this.count++;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log("onDestroy of ReceiverComponent " + this.id)
    //this cause "Cannot subscribe to a disposed Subject."
    //this.eventService.myEvent.unsubscribe();
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

In fact, `EventEmitter`s are shared observables, i.e. hot observables. Here is a link that could interest you: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/creating.md.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry