# how to unsubscribe several subscriber in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have shareService and subscribe that is in another components :

```
import { Component, Input, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { MissionService } from './mission.service';
import { Subscription }   from 'rxjs/Subscription';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-astronaut',
  template: `
    <p>
      {{astronaut}}: <strong>{{mission}}</strong>
      <button
        (click)="confirm()"
        [disabled]="!announced || confirmed">
        Confirm
      </button>
    </p>
  `
})
export class AstronautComponent implements OnDestroy{
  @Input() astronaut: string;
  mission = "<no mission announced>";
  confirmed = false;
  announced = false;
  subscription:Subscription;

  constructor(private missionService: MissionService) {
    this.subscription = missionService.missionAnnounced$.subscribe(
      mission => {
        this.mission = mission;
        this.announced = true;
        this.confirmed = false;
    })




  }
  confirm() {
    this.confirmed = true;
    this.missionService.confirmMission(this.astronaut);
  }
  ngOnDestroy(){
    // prevent memory leak when component destroyed
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();

  }
}
```

I want to know if I have 2 subscribers in my `constructor`, how to unsubscribe twice subscribers in ngDestroy?
I should use `subscription2:Subscription;`?and in ngDestroy `this.subscription2.unsubscribe();`?
this is true?

Comment: Yes, you need a different `subscriptionX` variable where you assign the 2nd subscription. And then call `.unsubscribe()` on each.

Comment: You can also use an array of subscriptions and use `this.subscriptions.push(myService.subscribe(...))` and then do `this.subscriptions.forEach((s) => s.unsubscribe())`

Comment: `this.subscriptions.push(myService.subscribe(...))` not working...cant push!

Comment: It needs to be initialized `subscription:Subscription[] = [];

Comment: tnx it worked... :) it's better than you have several subscriptionX

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can collect subscriptions that you want to unsubscribe at once in `ngOnDestroy()` in an array

```
export class AstronautComponent implements OnDestroy{
  @Input() astronaut: string;
  mission = "<no mission announced>";
  confirmed = false;
  announced = false;
  subscriptions:Subscription[] = [];

  constructor(private missionService: MissionService) {
    this.subscriptions.push(missionService.missionAnnounced$.subscribe(
      mission => {
        this.mission = mission;
        this.announced = true;
        this.confirmed = false;
    }));

    this.subscriptions.push(fooService.fooObservable$.subscribe(
      ...
    }));
  }

  confirm() {
    this.confirmed = true;
    this.missionService.confirmMission(this.astronaut);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    // prevent memory leak when component destroyed
    this.subscriptions.forEach(s => s.unsubscribe());
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `this.subscriptions.push()` ?

Comment: Thanks. Mixed in some Dart by accident :-/

Answer (score 21):

A `Subscription` can hold child subscriptions and safely unsubscribe them all. This method handles possible errors (e.g. if any child subscriptions are null). Also, if any subscriptions are added after `ngOnDestroy` is called, they will be immediately unsubscribed.

It should be noted that `Subscription.add()` returns the **added** subscription. So chaining `add()` like `subManager.add(sub1).add(sub2)` will add `sub2` to `sub1`. This will be an issue if `sub1` is unsubscribed at an earlier time, as it will also unsubscribe from `sub2`.

```
import { OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs/Subscription";

export class MyComponent implements OnDestroy {
    ob1: Observable<number>;
    ob2: Observable<number>;
    subManager = new Subscription();

    constructor() {
        this.ob1 = Observable.interval(1000);
        this.ob2 = Observable.interval(2000);

        let sub1 = this.ob1.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
        let sub2 = this.ob2.subscribe(val => console.log(val));

        // DO NOT CHAIN add() - SEE ABOVE
        this.subManager.add(sub1);
        this.subManager.add(sub2);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subManager.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

From the [documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscription.js~Subscription.html):

> Additionally, subscriptions may be grouped together through the add()
>   method, which will attach a child Subscription to the current
>   Subscription. When a Subscription is unsubscribed, all its children
>   (and its grandchildren) will be unsubscribed as well.
>
> ...
>
> If this subscription is already in an closed state, the passed tear
>   down logic will be executed immediately.

Comment: Yeah, my question was for angular beta

Comment: Is there an advantage to doing this this way versus an array of subscriptions like in the accepted answer?

Comment: Yes, I listed the advantages I could think of - see top paragraph. The same null and closed state checks could be done with the array of subscriptions, but that is exactly what a Subscription is. There is no point redoing it all in your component.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, more elegant and universal (does not matter how many subscription you have) is to use takeUntil operators from rxjs package.

```
import { OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class MyComponent implements OnDestroy {

    ob1: any;
    ob2: any;

    private _endSubs: Subject<any> = new Subject();
    private endSubs$ = this._endSubs.asObservable();

    constructor() {
        this.ob1 = Observable.interval(1000);
        this.ob2 = Observable.interval(2000);

        let sub1 = this.ob1.pipe(takeUntil(this.endSubs$)).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
        let sub2 = this.ob2.pipe(takeUntil(this.endSubs$)).subscribe(val => console.log(val));

        .... (more subscriptions here)
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this._endSubs.next();
    }
}
```