# Error when redirecting between components in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-services

This is the home page of my app.  It gets redirected to if someone tries to access a page when they aren't logged in.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx'; 

import { AuthenticationService } from '../_services/authentication.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  model: any = { username: "", password: "" };
  loading = false;
  error = '';
  isLoggedIn = false;
  public currentUser: any = null;
  constructor(private _auth: AuthenticationService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if(this._auth.isLoggedIn()) {
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
      this.router.navigate(['/census']);
    }
    else {

    }

    this.currentUser = this._auth.getCurrentUser().subscribe(result => {
      this.currentUser = result;
    });

    /*let timer = Observable.timer(29000, 29000);
    timer.subscribe(t => {

      //this.refresh();
    });*/
  }

  login() {
        this.loading = true;
        this._auth.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
            .subscribe(result => {
                if (result === true) {
                    // login successful
                    this.isLoggedIn = true;
                    this.router.navigate(['/census']);
                } else {
                    // login failed
                    this.error = 'Username or password is incorrect';
                    this.loading = false;
                }
            });
    }

}
```

I have the same problem on any page I try redirecting to.  The line that has

```
this.currentUser = this._auth.getCurrentUser().subscribe(result => {
  this.currentUser = result;
});
```

The error is

```
error_handler.js:54 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: this._auth.getCurrentUser(...).subscribe is not a function
```

Gives me an error.  It only gives an error if I redirected to the page using `router.navigate(['/']);`

I've tried `navigateByUrl` and get the same result.  This is on the top of every page, and I get the error any time I redirect to the page.

This is the getCurrentUser method from the AuthenticationService

```
    getCurrentUser(): Observable<any> {
        if (this.currentUser == null) {
            let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token') });
            let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
            return this.http.get(  this._api.apiUrl + 'users/0', options)
                .map((response: Response) => {
                    this.currentUser = response.json();
                    return this.currentUser;
                });
        }
        else {
            return this.currentUser;
        }
  }
```

Comment: you should import the authProvider in every component(or do it in some shared service). In every component you have to pass your auth object to the constructor to make it available in your (newly instantiated after a redirect) component

Comment: @Rienk I updated my question.  I do import it on every page and include it in my constructor as shown above.

Comment: Please post the full component this is too little information. The only thing I dont understand is the dot (./) in your route target: this._router.navigate(['./encounter-billing/' + index]);

Comment: @Rienk I pasted the entire code from a shorter page.  I have the same problem on any page that I redirect to.

Comment: `this._auth.getCurrentUser(...).subscribe is not a function` - that seems clear. What does your `getCurrentUser` function look like?

Comment: @hdk I added the code for that, but hear the distinction I'm making.  That method works fine.  If I have a href html redirect it works fine.  Every time.  It only doesn't work if I redirect programmatically  using the router.

Comment: Friendly advice, if you want to prevent users from accessing routes of your app if they are not logged in. You should read and learn about Guards https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

Comment: You're not returning an observable from `getCurrentUser` when `this.currentUser` is not `null`, only when it is `null`.

Comment: @hdk That's it!  Since I'm redirecting it doesn't need to call it down again and doesn't return anything.  If you post that as the answer I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: @FabioAntunes I am using authGuard on my routes, that was a poor choice of wording on my part.

Comment: @hdk I am returning something though if it's not null, I guess it's that I'm returning something that's not subscribable?  How would I change my return to make it something subscribable?

Comment: Just change `return this.currentUser;` to `return Observable.of(this.currentUser);`

Comment: @hdk Thanks, if you post is as an answer I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than returning the user object when it already exists, transform it with the `Observable of` operator to return an Observable.

Change `return this.currentUser;` to `return Observable.of(this.currentUser);` in the Authentication Service.

Also this is a bit off:

```
this.currentUser = this._auth.getCurrentUser().subscribe(result => {
  this.currentUser = result;
});
```

`currentUser` is being set to the `Subscription` of `getCurrentUser()` and then subsequently the result (`subscribe()` returns a `Subscription`).

Comment: How would you recommend I change it?

Comment: The subscription? The typical pattern is to save the subscription (in a separate property) and then unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy` to ensure it's removed.

Comment: Could you point me to an example?  I want to make sure I'm doing it right.

Comment: Something like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34926698/3244479

Comment: This answer though goes into a lot of detail and suggests a newer approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41177163/3244479